# Joomla does not properly force ssl

Tags: ssl, https, joomla, joomla2.5

**Current situation**

- I've got an old installation of joomla 2.5.28 (blauwelint.nl).
- There is a ssl-certificate installed from LetsEncrypt, works like it should.
- Force SSL is set to entire site in Joomla settings
- Added the following to htaccess to force www:

  ```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.nl [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.nl/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
  ```

https://domain.nl works without errors

**Expected behaviour**: always force https

**Actual behaviour**
In a fresh browser it appears also possible to open the site with just http://, regardles of the fact that force ssl is set.

**Question**
I want https to be forced always, but can't figure out why expected behaviour isnt followed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally do not use the Joomla setting and just use .htaccess rules. If you turn off force SSL in Joomla, you can use the following to force https and www:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.blauwelint.\nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.blauwelint.nl/$1 [L,R=301]
```

EDIT: Also, be careful sharing your Joomla version and domain. Support for 2.5.x has ended.

Comment: *be careful sharing your Joomla version and domain* You're totally right, thnx, i edited the question

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on Joomla 2.5 and 3.x websites:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```